# Renewal opportunity

Tags: opportunity

A Renewal Opportunity button is available on the Service Contract page. When the button is clicked, a Renewal Sales Opportunity is created with Opportunity Products associated to the Assets associated to the Service Contract Line Items.
Here renewal opportunity is a renewal sales opportunity record type. 
I am thinking how to start. DO I have to create a record type and assign page layout and set controller for the page. Any ideas will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you need the record type that you will be creating the record in to be created. So that's a good place to start. Second I'd probably make the button, then third make the class that will perform the record creation logic.

It sounds like you're logic will be(and need methods for each):

- Query for OpportunityLineItem data to add to Opportunity
- Create new Opportunity record
- Create OpportunityLineItems with queried data.